# Access the data from Central DB inside tenant domain and vice versa Stancl/Tenancy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, multi-tenant

**Description**

Is there any way to switch the DB environment in [Stancl/Tenancy](https://github.com/stancl/tenancy) module?
As I earlier worked with some other tenancy modules, I use to switch the environment when I want to access some resources from the central domain inside the tenants and vice versa.

**Why this should be added**

I was trying to get the plans and features for the tenants, and want to get some more data from the central domain (DB). for eg, I have named subscriptions and plans table both for the tenants and central users, when I try to fetch the subscription of the tenant user from the central domain it is returning the data from the tenant DB.

```
namespace App\Helpers;
use App\Models\System\Admin\Subscription;
 public static function checkTenantPlan()
    {
        // Find the tenant
        // get the tenantId and find that
        $tenant_user_id = tenant()->user_id;
        // Find the subscription of the tenant User
        $subscription = Subscription::where('user_id', $tenant_user_id)
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->first();
        return $subscription->plan(); //returning the data from the current tenant db
        
    }
```

Comment: Do the tenant databases and your central domain database reside on the same MySQL server machine?

Comment: Yes, look for the stancl/tenancy docs for more info.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has been fixed in a new release.
https://github.com/stancl/tenancy/releases/tag/v3.3.0

```
$tenant->run(function ($tenant) {
    return User::all();
});

tenancy()->central(function ($tenant) {
    return User::all();
});
```

Comment: This works for the `central domain` but not for the tenant. I'm getting the error `"Database connection [tenant] not configured."` Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch inside the tenant or central level?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this link [Central App](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v2/central-app/)

Set up another connections in database.php and use
 `DB::connection($connectionName)->table('foo')->where(...)`